# SSRS REPORT RENAME programmatically

Tags: reporting-services

I need to rename a report in SSRS. I can do it manually in Visual studio by renaming it in solution explorer, but due to some requirement I need avoid manual method. How can we programmatically rename a report in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at what you are after. I assume you are not talking about the Report Viewer control and and you want to change the name of the report file that is streamed to the client?
You can use the Content-Disposition HTTP header, as in:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(localReport.Render(reportFormat,
      null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
      out streamids, out warnings));

switch (reportFormat) {
    case "Excel":
       Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+_your name_);
       break;
    case "PDF":
....
```